# Using Robotium with a contextual menu

Tags: robotium, android-testing

I'm testing an application with Robotium, and I have a custom listview with checkboxes. When I click on a checkbox it loads a contextual menu giving the user buttons to modify and delete those items.

I can get Robotium to click the checkbox which loads the menu, but for some reason I can't get it to click on the delete button.

I've tried:

```
solo.clickOnActionBarItem(R.id.menu_delete);
solo.clickOnMenuItem("Delete");
solo.clickOnImageButton(1);
solo.clickOnImage(1);
```

So far nothing has worked. Is it possibly because I am clicking the button before the menu has popped up? How can I get Robotium to wait?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually very easy, just click on the view by id:

```
solo.clickOnView(getActivity().findViewById(R.id.menu_edit));
```

Comment: This solution works ONLY when the menu_edit is displayed, if its with "ifRoom" and thus hidden in submenu - it will not work and I couldn't find any other solution. Posted it on Robotium as well:https://github.com/RobotiumTech/robotium/issues/792